# Error: Compile Error: unexpected token: 'List'

Tags: apex, class, list

Getting this error:
Error: Compile Error: unexpected token: 'List'

```
 public String SupportTierValue {
  get {


    List tmpAcct = [SELECT Id, Name, Support_Tier__c
    FROM Account
    WHERE Id IN 
    (SELECT AccountId 
    FROM user 
    WHERE username=:UserInfo.getUsername()
    )
    LIMIT 1
    ];
    if (tmpAcct.size() > 0) {
    String SupportTier = tmpAcct[0].Support_Tier__c;
    }
    else {
    String SupportTier = 'SomeDefaultValue';
    }



}
return SupportTierValue;
 }
private set;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

`List` requires a "specialization", such as `List<Account>` in your code example.

Comment: Thank you. Now I get an error : Error: Compile Error: expecting right curly bracket, found 'return' .   I tried the right curly bracket and nothing

Comment: @ObiDarrell the } before the return statement is unbalanced. Remove that one from your code.